# How to prevent modification of objects in Collection without making the type a struct?

Tags: c#, collections, struct

Take the following example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Stack<Data> s = new Stack<Data>();

        Data d = new Data( 10 );

        s.Push( d );

        d.Value = 20;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Data
{
    public int Value;

    public Data( int value )
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Without making `Data` a `struct` is there any way I can stop the `d` instance that is being put onto the stack from having it's object properties updated by the `d.Value = 20` line?  When `d` is pushed onto the stack, it's `Value` property is assigned a value of `10`, but when the property is amended it's changed to `20`.  Is there any other way I can stop this without resorting to structs or cloning classes?

I'm asking this because I am writing a chess engine and as part of the search and evaluation it needs to move chess pieces around the board.  When putting boards on the stack, so that I can create sub-analysis boards it is affecting the boards already on the stack.

Comment: Just make it an "immutable" type: `public int Value { get; private set; }` (And if the outside code wants to change the value, it must itself deal with creating a copy.)

Comment: You may want to check [value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). But it still is kind of cloning.

Comment: Bear in mind I am only using a simplified example to demonstrate my point.  A real world example would be far too long and complex to explain here so I used this example instead.  I have considered cloning and want to avoid this as this will hurt the engine search performance so it's not an option.  I may have to ditch classes and use a struct instead, but that will be difficult as the board class is extremely large and contains reference types.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please, take a look if the question is still actual for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no conceivable way of converting the `Board` class into a `struct` as it is too large and has a lot of reference types so I have decided against using a Stack object to store instances of chess boards.

Instead, I created a `BoardManager` static class to store all individually created chess boards in a list, and when I need a certain board I simply retrieve it using the board's identifier.

Answer (score 0):

No way. Since you use reference type it should change all your instances. If you use simple type for *Value* as you mention before I suggest you to use [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

**Update:**

How about this implementation :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Stack<Data> s = new Stack<Data>();

  Data d = new Data(10);
  d.Freeze();

  s.Push(d);

  d.Value = 20;

  Console.WriteLine("Frozen value : {0}", s.Pop().Value);
  Console.WriteLine("actual value : {0}", d.Actual(data => data.Value));
  Console.ReadKey();
}

  class FreezableValue<T>
  {
    private T frozenValue;
    private T actualValue;
    private bool isFrozen;

    public void Freeze()
    {
      isFrozen = true;
    }

    public T ActualValue
    {
      get
      {
        return actualValue;
      }
      set
      {
        this.actualValue = value;
        if(!isFrozen)
          frozenValue = value;
      }
    }

    public T FrozenValue { get { return frozenValue; } }
  }

  class Data
  {
    private readonly FreezableValue<int> freezableValue;
    private bool useActualValue;

    public Data(int value)
    {
      freezableValue = new FreezableValue<int> { ActualValue = value };
      useActualValue = true;
    }

    public void Freeze()
    {
      freezableValue.Freeze();
      useActualValue = false;
    }

    public int Value
    {
      get { return useActualValue ? freezableValue.ActualValue : freezableValue.FrozenValue; }
      set { freezableValue.ActualValue = value; }
    }

    public T Actual<T>(Func<Data, T> func)
    {
      useActualValue = true;
      try
      {
        return func(this);
      }
      finally
      {
        useActualValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Then what would be the point of using a stack for reference types if once cannot guarantee the instances won't have their properties changed?  Cloning is not an option as performance is critical to the speed of the search.

Comment: Stacks are unrelated to the mutability of the objects they contain.  Their only goal is to provide a LIFO (Last in, First Out) access model.  They make no guarantees about the objects they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class Data implement a readonly Interface:

```
 public interface IReadOnlyData {

    int SomeInt { get;}
    string SomeString {get;}
}
```

Then your Stack can be:

```
Stack<IReadOnlyData> stack = new Stack<IReadOnlyData>();
```

Comment: That doesn't prevent whoever puts a data element into the stack from modifying it, it only prevents whoever pulls data *off* of the stack from modifying it (unless they cast it).

Comment: @servy how else would it get modified?

Comment: As I said, whoever puts it on the stack may well have a reference to the concrete type, not the interface, and could mutate it.  Why *wouldn't* they be able to mutate it?

Comment: @servy using that stance you could also use reflection on an object and do whatever you want. He wanted a stack with objects you can't change...